# Is there any way to list all git repositories in terminal?

Tags: git, terminal

I have several git repositories on my system and I want to list them all in terminal.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
/path/to/my/git/repo/1/ REPONAME1  
/path/to/my/git/repo/2/ REPONAME2  
/path/to/my/git/repo/3/ REPONAME3
```

If you can come up with how to show branch name and repo's status eg. `[master] c:0 u:1 d:0`, that would be great.

Comment: This is a bit similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765253/git-status-across-multiple-repositories-on-a-mac where you can also find useful ideas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To list all the git repositories you have on your system you can run the following command in a bash shell terminal (at the command line) and find them.

```
find / -name .git -type d -exec dirname {} \;
```

Comment: This is a reasonable first approximation, but misses a lot.  Bare repositories will be missed, as will any repos that use a regular file named .git to specify a git directory.

Comment: *`C:\xampp\htdocs\rimedit>`* `find / -name .git -type d -exec dirname {} \`
`"C:/Users/Jakub/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit_fed20eba68b3e238e49a47cdfed0a45
783d93651/bin/find.exe":` **`missing argument to `-exec'`**

Answer (score 6):

I found this more accurate than the find command and much faster.  I'm sure it can be improved but it's a good start.  Obviously your file database will need to be up-to-date before running this command.  On linux systems you can do this by running `sudo updatedb`.

```
locate -br '\.git$' | rev | cut -c 6- | rev
```

Answer (score 5):

> If you can come up with how to show branch name and repo's status

The idea is to:

- (first) find and register the repositories,
- then use the new (Git 2.30, Q4 2020) [`git for-each-repo` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-repo).

First, chose any config key name you want.
For example: "`list.repos`"

Reinitialize the list, using [`git config --unset-all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---unset) (in the global config file):

```
git config --global --unset-all list.repos
```

Then use either:

- [nrbray/find_gits](https://gist.github.com/nrbray/a0ae8ec59d1fd1ae03e2947368096d2e) (Perl script, which uses `find`, not [`locate`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/))
- [`uncommitted/`](https://pypi.org/project/uncommitted/) (Python, which uses `find` by default, or [`locate`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) if needed)

Redirect the result in a file 'list-repos.txt', then register those repositories, [reading each line of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521498/6309):

```bash
while IFS="" read -r repo || [ -n "${repo}" ]
do
  git config --global --add list.repos ${repo}
done < list-repos.txt
```

Once your repositories are registered (as global git config values), it is trivial to loop over them using the new command [**`git for-each-repo`**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-repo), executing any command you need.

With Git 2.30 (Q4 2020), a new command is introduced, initially to manage parts of "[`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7660da161821ab79b8ecd5019c28843ed7e770a6/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup> and to ease writing crontab entries (and other scheduling system configuration) for it.

See [commit 0016b61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0016b618182f642771dc589cf0090289f9fe1b4f), [commit 61f7a38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61f7a383d3b9a7306f1fd44a8dfa070deacc0752), [commit a4cb1a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4cb1a2339c1aa4ba71ebc6d2b07d537e1071124) (15 Oct 2020), [commit 2fec604](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2fec604f8df51fcf47551723e68a3447915b9eb9), [commit 0c18b70](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c18b700810ab2e2a4fac0d5b54a817141198a27), [commit 4950b2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4950b2a2b5c4731e4c9d5b803739a6979b23fed6), [commit b08ff1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b08ff1fee000230ad22fee823aabff2613bd4e62) (11 Sep 2020), and [commit 1942d48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1942d48380fec53f76361e9adebef15b5db9628a) (28 Aug 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7660da1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7660da161821ab79b8ecd5019c28843ed7e770a6), 18 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`for-each-repo`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4950b2a2b5c4731e4c9d5b803739a6979b23fed6): run subcommands on configured repos
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> It can be helpful to store a list of repositories in global or system config and then iterate Git commands on that list.
> Create a new builtin that makes this process simple for experts.
> We will use this builtin to run scheduled maintenance on all configured repositories in a future change.
>
> The test is very simple, but does highlight that the "`--`" argument is optional.

`git for-each-repo` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4950b2a2b5c4731e4c9d5b803739a6979b23fed6/Documentation/git-for-each-repo.txt#L1-L59):

> ## git-for-each-repo(1)
>
> ### NAME
>
> `git-for-each-repo` - Run a Git command on a list of repositories
>
> ### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> [verse]
> 'git for-each-repo' --config=<config> [--] <arguments>
> ```
>
> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> Run a Git command on a list of repositories. The arguments after the
> known options or `--` indicator are used as the arguments for the Git
> subprocess.
>
> THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE.
>
> For example, we could run maintenance on each of a list of repositories
> stored in a `maintenance.repo` config variable using
>
> ---
>
> ### git for-each-repo --config=maintenance.repo maintenance run
>
> This will run `git -C <repo> maintenance run` for each value `<repo>`
> in the multi-valued config variable `maintenance.repo`.
>
> ### OPTIONS
>
> ### `--config=<config>`
>
> Use the given config variable as a multi-valued list storing
> absolute path names. Iterate on that list of paths to run
> the given arguments.
>
> These config values are loaded from system, global, and local Git config,
> as available. If `git for-each-repo` is run in a directory that is not a
> Git repository, then only the system and global config is used.
>
> ### SUBPROCESS BEHAVIOR
>
> If any `git -C <repo> <arguments>` subprocess returns a non-zero exit code,
> then the `git for-each-repo` process returns that exit code without running
> more subprocesses.
>
> Each `git -C <repo> <arguments>` subprocess inherits the standard file
> descriptors `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.

---

With Git 2.30.1 (Q1 2021), "[`git for-each-repo --config=<var> <cmd>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aa08688362448e0f74ed776449e80d54ca9ae909/Documentation/git-for-each-repo.txt#L36)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-repo#Documentation/git-for-each-repo.txt---configltconfiggt))</sup> should not run `<cmd>` for any repository when the configuration variable `<var>` is not defined even once.

See [commit 6c62f01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c62f015520eaecd94d93a7e8339b190f2c24bc6) (08 Jan 2021) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit aa08688](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa08688362448e0f74ed776449e80d54ca9ae909), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`for-each-repo`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c62f015520eaecd94d93a7e8339b190f2c24bc6): do nothing on empty config
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Andreas Bühmann</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> '[`git for-each-repo --config=X`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c62f015520eaecd94d93a7e8339b190f2c24bc6/Documentation/git-for-each-repo.txt#L36)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-repo#Documentation/git-for-each-repo.txt---configltconfiggt))</sup> should return success without calling any subcommands when the config key '`X`' has no value.
> The current implementation instead segfaults.
>
> A user could run into this issue if they used '[`git maintenance start`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c62f015520eaecd94d93a7e8339b190f2c24bc6/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L65)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt-start))</sup> to initialize their cron schedule using '[`git for-each-repo --config=maintenance.repo ...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c62f015520eaecd94d93a7e8339b190f2c24bc6/Documentation/git-for-each-repo.txt#L36)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-repo#Documentation/git-for-each-repo.txt---configltconfiggt))</sup> but then using '[`git maintenance unregister`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c62f015520eaecd94d93a7e8339b190f2c24bc6/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L76)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt-unregister))</sup> to remove the config option.
> (Note: '[`git maintenance stop`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c62f015520eaecd94d93a7e8339b190f2c24bc6/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L71)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt-stop))</sup> would remove the config *and* remove the cron schedule.)
>
> Add a simple test to ensure this works.
> Use '[`git help --no-such-option`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c62f015520eaecd94d93a7e8339b190f2c24bc6/Documentation/git-help.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help))</sup> as the potential subcommand to ensure that we will hit a failure if the subcommand is ever run.

---

Note: with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), '[`git for-each-repo`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/56a64fcdc32568cfe1db34c44767a740d25d6d21/Documentation/git-for-each-repo.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-repo))</sup> is taught to expand tilde characters in paths.

See [commit 03744bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03744bbdc4284fbb358abd5347c8bb157f301243) (15 Nov 2022) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
See [commit be0fd57](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be0fd5722853e56fab8bc99cea9791d7b90fd0dd) (15 Nov 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
See [commit 1f80129](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f80129d61bcc9a77b34b30bc42b2770b4b96deb), [commit 13d5bbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13d5bbdf72aab109c9b69994c90aaff2a0b7e42f) (09 Nov 2022) by [Ronan Pigott (`RPigott`)](https://github.com/RPigott).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 56a64fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56a64fcdc32568cfe1db34c44767a740d25d6d21), 23 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`for-each-repo`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13d5bbdf72aab109c9b69994c90aaff2a0b7e42f): interpolate repo path arguments
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ronan Pigott</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> This is a quality of life change for `git-maintenance`, so repos can be recorded with the tilde syntax.
> The register subcommand will not record repos in this format by default.

---

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), `git for-each-repo` is more robust:

See [commit 3611f74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3611f7467fddcff6063ed2c99484047b410969fc), [commit 9e2d884](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e2d884d0fcf0631164c33d458a251bee6053bb1), [commit 1c7e239](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c7e239bd0bc91d6296835e30fa597b8c56e752d), [commit f7b2ff9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7b2ff95163247a3ec437f0ce78bb27cdac68b75), [commit a428619](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a428619309f42b76b5f750e66a5c1fd2225db3b3), [commit f6f348a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6f348a6d5d585fb3eda326a20bf2bab9e60ef51), [commit b83efce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b83efcecaf12884d2bbb72b8ef2e4528205a0b02), [commit e7587a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7587a8f53e84d4b666c0107987b0a9fa2f8336d), [commit 258902c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/258902ce07779a6ca532d092279c1554a199ba2a) (28 Mar 2023) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 87daf40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87daf40750c9e344dd50495fdca1809aebcb1a94), 06 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`for-each-repo`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3611f7467fddcff6063ed2c99484047b410969fc): with bad config, don't conflate  and
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix a logic error in [4950b2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4950b2a2b5c4731e4c9d5b803739a6979b23fed6) ("`for-each-repo`: run subcommands on configured repos", 2020-09-11, Git v2.30.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7660da161821ab79b8ecd5019c28843ed7e770a6) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475)).
> Due to assuming that elements returned from the `repo_config_get_value_multi()` call wouldn't be "`NULL`" we'd conflate the `<path>` and `<command>` part of the argument list when running commands.
>
> As noted in the preceding commit the fix is to move to a safer "`*_string_multi()`" version of the `*_multi()` API.
> This change is separated from the rest because those all segfaulted.
> In this change we ended up with different behavior.
>
> When using the "`--config=<config>`" form we take each element of the list as a path to a repository.
> E.g.
> with a configuration like:
>
> ```
> [repo] list = /some/repo
> ```
>
> We would, with this command:
>
> ```
> git for-each-repo --config=repo.list status builtin
> ```
>
> Run a "[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3611f7467fddcff6063ed2c99484047b410969fc/Documentation/git-status.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> in /some/repo, as:
>
> ```
> git -C /some/repo status builtin
> ```
>
> I.e.
> ask "`status`" to report on the "`builtin`" directory.
> But since a configuration such as this would result in a "`struct string_list *`" with one element, whose "`string`" member is "`NULL`":
>
> ```
> [repo] list
> ```
>
> We would, when constructing our command-line in "[`builtin/for-each-repo.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3611f7467fddcff6063ed2c99484047b410969fc/builtin/for-each-repo.c)"...
>
> ```
> strvec_pushl(&child.args, "-C", path, NULL);
> for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
>   strvec_push(&child.args, argv[i]);
> ```
>
> ...have that "`path`" be "`NULL`", and as `strvec_pushl()` stops when it sees `NULL` we'd end with the first "`argv`" element as the argument to the "`-C`" option, e.g.:
>
> ```
> git -C status builtin
> ```
>
> I.e.
> we'd run the command "`builtin`" in the "`status`" directory.
>
> In another context this might be an interesting security vulnerability, but I think that this amounts to a nothingburger on that front.
>
> A hypothetical attacker would need to be able to write config for the victim to run, if they're able to do that there's more interesting attack vectors.
> See the "safe.directory" facility added in [8d1a744](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d1a7448206e11cdea657c35b04cc49db39be933) ("[`setup.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d1a7448206e11cdea657c35b04cc49db39be933/setup.c): create `safe.bareRepository`", 2022-07-14, Git v2.38.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18bbc795fc52dc543e279c213fd1bfe27afc6092) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a475b71f8c4ce708d69fdc9317aefbde3769e25)).
>
> An even more unlikely possibility would be an attacker able to generate the config used for "`for-each-repo --config=<key>`", but nothing else (e.g. an automated system producing that list).
>
> Even in that case the attack vector is limited to the user running commands whose name matches a directory that's interesting to the attacker (e.g. a "`log`" directory in a repository).
> The second argument (if any) of the command is likely to make git die without doing anything interesting (e.g. "`-p`" to "`log`", there being no "`-p`" built-in command to run).

Comment: the perl and python repo-finders are kinda heavy for a oneliner, and at least the perl one gets it a bit wrong, it will miss valid repos. `find -name HEAD -execdir test -d refs -a -d objects \; -printf %h\\n` will do it, on Macs you need the brew `find` I think. You can use ``(IFS=$'\n'; find `locate */HEAD`…)`` etc to speed up locating repos that weren't cloned or inited since the last updatedb.

Comment: @jthill Agree. This answer is *not* about a one-liner approach. It is to illustrate the new command.

Answer (score 4):

[lsgit](https://github.com/DeeNewcum/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/lsgit) is a script that does this.  It's essentially a wrapper around `locate -br '^HEAD$'`.

If there are multiple clones of the same repo on the local machine, it will indicate that those repos are related.

Answer (score 3):

With Powershell you can add all repositories to a global git variable using a script like this:

```
$dirName = Split-Path -Path ./ -Leaf
$repoProp = "$dirName.repos"

$repos = Get-ChildItem . `
    -Attributes Directory+Hidden `
    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
    -Filter ".git" `
    -Recurse

git config --global --unset-all $repoProp
$repos | ForEach-Object { git config --global --add $repoProp $_.Parent.FullName }
```

Copy the script in the root folder and then run it.
Then you can use `git for-each-repo` command as explained by VonC.

Answer (score 1):

A wrapper around:
`locate -br '^HEAD$'` 
as done by Dee Newcum https://github.com/DeeNewcum/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/lsgit or else `find . -name 'HEAD'` as modified in https://gist.github.com/nrbray/a0ae8ec59d1fd1ae03e2947368096d2e

gives an alternative to searching for gits by the folder or filename alone.

[Not enough reputation to comment on Dee's answer, but I used his solution and it worked for me]

Comment: Please earn reputation and then comment adding comment as answer mislead.