# How to quickly find all git repos under a directory

Tags: bash

Update: The title of this question is misleading. Apologies. In the sample code below, however, there is `git pull`. This is the purpose: to update a tree of git repos. No need to list them. I show a `bash` script, but that language does not have good support for managing parallel processes. For best results, another language should be used.

The following `bash` script is slow when scanning for .git directories because it looks at every directory. If I have a collection of large repositories it takes a long time for find to churn through every directory, looking for .git. It would go much faster if it would prune the directories within repos, once a .git directory is found. Any ideas on how to do that, or is there another way to write a script/program that accomplishes the same thing?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Update all git directories below current directory or specified directory

HIGHLIGHT="\e[01;34m"
NORMAL='\e[00m'

DIR=.
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then DIR=$1; fi
cd $DIR>/dev/null; echo -e "${HIGHLIGHT}Scanning ${PWD}${NORMAL}"; cd ->/dev/null

for d in `find . -name .git -type d`; do
  cd $d/.. > /dev/null
  echo -e "\n${HIGHLIGHT}Updating `pwd`$NORMAL"
  git pull
  cd - > /dev/null
done
```

---

Specifically, how would you use these options? For this problem, you cannot assume that the collection of repos is all in the same directory; they might be within nested directories.

```
top
  repo1
  dirA
     
  dirB
     dirC
        repo1
```

Comment: Consider adding the `-maxdepth` option and setting it to `1` (for `find`)

Comment: Just add the `-prune` option should word.

Comment: Specifically, how would you use these options? For this problem, you cannot assume that the collection of repos is all in the same directory; they might be within nested directories.

    top
      repo1
      dirA
         repo2
         repo3
         repo4
      dirB
         repo5
         dirC
            repo6

Comment: Is it the `find` that is "slow", or is it the fact that you're doing a `git pull` at each directory? I suspect simply running `find . -type d -name .git -print` should be pretty quick (unless you're running over a slow network file system like NFS or CIFS, or on a floppy drive or something)...

Comment: temporarily remove the pull; see if it is still slow

Comment: Clay, you are another victim of groupthink. Try running the script and you will see that you don't understand how it works.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333862/how-to-find-all-git-repositories-within-given-folders-fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer combines the partial answer provided @Greg Barrett with my optimized answer above.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Update all git directories below current directory or specified directory
# Skips directories that contain a file called .ignore

HIGHLIGHT="\e[01;34m"
NORMAL='\e[00m'

export PATH=${PATH/':./:'/:}
export PATH=${PATH/':./bin:'/:}
#echo "$PATH"

DIRS="$( find "$@" -type d \( -execdir test -e {}/.ignore \; -prune \) -o \( -execdir test -d {}/.git \; -prune -print \) )"

echo -e "${HIGHLIGHT}Scanning ${PWD}${NORMAL}"
for d in $DIRS; do
  cd "$d" > /dev/null
  echo -e "\n${HIGHLIGHT}Updating `pwd`$NORMAL"
  git pull 2> >(sed -e 's/X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0//')
  cd - > /dev/null
done
```

Answer (score 72):

Check out Dennis' answer in this post about find's -prune option:

[How to use '-prune' option of 'find' in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh)

```
find . -name .git -type d -prune
```

Will speed things up a bit, as find won't descend into .git directories, but it still does descend into git repositories, looking for other .git folders. And that 'could' be a costly operation.

What would be cool is if there was some sort of find lookahead pruning mechanism, where if a folder has a subfolder called .git, then prune on that folder...

That said, I'm betting your bottleneck is in the network operation 'git pull', and not in the find command, as others have posted in the comments.

Comment: Dennis, you also have not tried your answer, and you also don't understand how the script works. You did not indentify the bottleneck correctly. If you folks run the script you will see it does not work the way you think it does. I don't intend to be mean, but you folks are all making the same conceptual errors. Negative groupthink.

Comment: This works, though I'm not sure it satisfies the "quick" constraint.  :P Thanks for this though!

Comment: The "lookahead" you mentioned is described by @vaab in his answer, a shorter (but perhaps weaker) version is: `find -type d -execdir test -d {}/.git \; -print -prune` .

Comment: Adding `-maxdepth 2` (1 or 2 depending on how deep you want to go) makes it even faster, especially in git bash under Windows: 


```find -maxdepth 2 -type d -execdir test -d {}/.git \; -print -prune```

Comment: To build up on this answer, I found this pretty useful for my scripts. Command is bash-specific though. 

`find . -name .git -type d -prune -exec dirname {} \;`

Comment: Well done! for those looking for an explanation: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.+-name+.git+-type+d+-prune

Answer (score 16):

Here is an optimized solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Update all git directories below current directory or specified directory
# Skips directories that contain a file called .ignore

HIGHLIGHT="\e[01;34m"
NORMAL='\e[00m'

function update {
  local d="$1"
  if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    if [ -e "$d/.ignore" ]; then 
      echo -e "\n${HIGHLIGHT}Ignoring $d${NORMAL}"
    else
      cd $d > /dev/null
      if [ -d ".git" ]; then
        echo -e "\n${HIGHLIGHT}Updating `pwd`$NORMAL"
        git pull
      else
        scan *
      fi
      cd .. > /dev/null
    fi
  fi
  #echo "Exiting update: pwd=`pwd`"
}

function scan {
  #echo "`pwd`"
  for x in $*; do
    update "$x"
  done
}

if [ "$1" != "" ]; then cd $1 > /dev/null; fi
echo -e "${HIGHLIGHT}Scanning ${PWD}${NORMAL}"
scan *
```

Comment: Looks good; but the fact that 'find' is compiled and bash is interpreted? makes me wonder if this is actually faster than the find method. Also not sure on bash's optimization of recursive functions. If you have time, care to post some benchmarks? I'd be interested to see the results.

Comment: The optimized version is dramatically faster. Try each version for yourself and stop wondering.

Comment: @MikeSlinn Your script doesn't work. I have a terminal dump to show you demonstrating the weird behavior but it's too big to post in a comment here... Basically it is not doing a very good job finding all the git repo's (how many it finds depends on which spot containing directory I run the script from) but still spends an **extremely long time** crawling everything.

Comment: I have used my script, and improved it, since posting. Works great.

Comment: use ``"$PWD"`` instead of ``pwd`` will make you gain some substantial time.

Comment: ${PWD} is essentially the same as $PWD. Note that `pwd` is commented out. Here is a more recent version, with better interop: https://gist.github.com/mslinn/3151915

Comment: To make the script above a slightly more robust, replace `cd $d > /dev/null` with `cd -- $d > /dev/null` since some git repositories like babel contain directories whose names start with a hyphen (e.g., `--extensions`).

Comment: @mmizutani the version in the gist quotes $d, so it is robust: cd "$d" > /dev/null

Comment: I updated the gist so it does not use ANSI colors if running as a cron job: http://gist.github.com/mslinn/3151915

Answer (score 14):

I've taken the time to copy-paste the script in your question, compare it to the script with your own answer. Here some interesting results:

Please note that:

- I've disabled the `git pull` by prefixing them with a `echo`
- I've removed also the color things
- I've removed also the `.ignore` file testing in the `bash` solution.
- And removed the unecessary `> /dev/null` here and there.
- removed `pwd` calls in both.
- added `-prune` which is obviously lacking in the `find` example
- used "while" instead of "for" which was also counter productive in the `find` example
- considerably untangled the second example to get to the point.
- added a test on the `bash` solution to NOT follow sym link to avoid cycles and behave as the find solution.
- added `shopt` to allow `*` to expand to dotted directory names also to match `find` solution's functionality.

Thus, we are comparing, the **find based solution**:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name .git -type d -prune | while read d; do
   cd $d/..
   echo "$PWD >" git pull
   cd $OLDPWD
done
```

With the **bash shell builting solution**:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob

update() {
    for d in "$@"; do
        test -d "$d" -a \! -L "$d" || continue
        cd "$d"
        if [ -d ".git" ]; then
            echo "$PWD >" git pull
        else
            update *
        fi
        cd ..
    done
}

update *
```

Note: builtins (`function` and the `for`) are immune to MAX_ARGS OS limit for launching processes. So the `*` won't break even on very large directories.

**Technical differences between solutions:**

The find based solution uses C function to crawl repository, it:

- has to load a new process for the `find` command.
- will avoid ".git" content but will crawl workdir of git repositories, and loose some
  times in those (and eventually find more matching elements).
- will have to `chdir` through several depth of sub-dir for each match and go back.
- will have to `chdir` once in the find command and once in the bash part.

The bash based solution uses builtin (so near-C implementation, but interpreted) to crawl repository, note that it:

- will use only one process.
- will avoid git workdir subdirectory.
- will only perform `chdir` one level at a time.
- will only perform `chdir` once for looking and performing the command.

**Actual speed results between solutions:**

I have a working development collection of git repository on which I launched the scripts:

- find solution: ~0.080s  (bash chdir takes ~0.010s)
- bash solution: ~0.017s

I have to admit that I wasn't prepared to see such a win from bash builtins. It became
more apparent and normal after doing the analysis of what's going on. To add insult to injuries, if you change the shell from `/bin/bash` to `/bin/sh` (you must comment out the `shopt` line, and be prepared that it won't parse dotted directories), you'll fall to 
~0.008s . Beat that !

Note that you can be more clever with the find solution by using:

```
find . -type d \( -exec /usr/bin/test -d "{}/.git" -a "{}" != "." \; -print -prune \
       -o -name .git -prune \)
```

which will effectively remove crawling all sub-repository in a found git repository, at the price of spawning a process for each directory crawled. The final find solution I came with was around ~0.030s, which is more than twice faster than the previous find version, but remains 2 times slower than the bash solution.

Note that `/usr/bin/test` is important to avoid search in `$PATH` which costs time, and I needed `-o -name .git -prune` and `-a "{}" != "."` because my main repository was itself a git subrepository.

As a conclusion, I won't be using the bash builtin solution because it has too much corner cases for me (and my first test hit one of the limitation). But it was important for me to explain why it could be (much) faster in some cases, but `find` solution seems much more robust and consistent to me.

Comment: I use the bash solution many times a day, on multiple OSes (Mac, Linux, Windows). It works very well. These are features:
 - won't parse sub-git repositories.
 - will follow symbolic links
 - won't look into directory with name starting with "."

Here is an updated script that has better interop:
https://gist.github.com/mslinn/3151915

Answer (score 10):

The answers above all rely on finding a ".git" repository. However not all git repos have these (e.g. bare repos). The following command will loop through all directories and ask git if it considers each to be a directory. If so, it prunes sub dirs off the tree and continues.

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "{}"; git rev-parse --git-dir 2> /dev/null 1>&2' \; -prune -print
```

It's a lot slower than other solutions because it's executing a command in each directory, but it doesn't rely on a particular repository structure. Could be useful for finding bare git repositories for example.

Comment: I have never needed to keep a bare git repo up to date by using "git pull", and I have never needed to locate a bare git repo via a recursive search. The performance hit for supporting these features would be significant.

Comment: Indeed they are, but I did find myself needing to locate bare repos recursively and, having looked through Stack Overflow for a solution and not found one, I decided to post mine here.

Comment: Cool. Why not make a gist of the entire working script and post the URL? I maintain a similar gist, shown above.

Comment: My script is bulky and does a lot of things that aren't really relevant to this question. The heart of it is the line above though: from there it's a simple `for f in "${output_of_above}; do` to loop through the results

Comment: This is a heck of a lot cheaper way to accomplish the same thing: `find docroot -type d -name ".git" -prune -print -exec rm -rf {} \;`. You don't want to target the based directory, but anything under that which might be problematic. In my case I am working with Drupal 8. So everything under the docroot directory is concerning.'

Comment: @pthurmond correct me if I’m wrong, but I think your method relies on detecting `.git` directories like the other methods. That’s fine in most cases, but some git repos (e.g. bare repos) don’t have one.

Comment: It does, but you should never be embedding other git repos into another repo except via automated processes that download the contents of those repos (such as using PHP composer or adding node modules). In that case you would always get the git directories.

Comment: But what if I have a normal folder which contains a load of unrelated bare repos, some of which are in subdirs for organisation?

Comment: You would have to target them specifically. Or wrap this in an iterator that runs this only in each subdirectory, but not the current one.

Comment: Or I could use git’s own mechanisms to identify valid directories, as in this answer. There are three possibilities for valid repositories. a) a .git folder exists. b) the repository is bare and contains no tree or c) the git files live elsewhere and are pointed at by a `.git` text file (see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout). My approach catches all these, recursively, albeit comparatively slowly.

Answer (score 6):

I list all git repositories anywhere in the current directory using:

```
find . -type d -execdir test -d {}/.git \\; -prune -print
```

This is fast since it stops recursing once it finds a git repository. (Although it does not handle bare repositories.) Of course, you can change the `.` to whatever directory you want. If you need, you can change the `-print` to `-print0` for null-separated values.

To also *ignore* directories containing a `.ignore` file:

```
find . -type d \( -execdir test -e {}/.ignore \; -prune \) -o \( -execdir test -d {}/.git \; -prune -print \)
```

I've added this alias to my `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
  repos =  !"find -type d -execdir test -d {}/.git \\; -prune -print"
```

Then I just need to execute:

```
git repos
```

To get a complete listing of all the git repositories anywhere in my current directory.

Comment: Nice! Can you add support for .ignore files, which cause the containing directory to be ignored? My current script does that and it is useful.

Comment: I should have included the `.ignore` file in my original answer. Oh well... it's in there now.

Comment: is there an extra backslash?  before -prune

Answer (score 3):

For windows, you can put the following into a batch file called gitlist.bat and put it on your PATH.

```
@echo off
if {%1}=={} goto :usage
for /r %1 /d %%I in (.) do echo %%I | find ".git\."
goto :eof
:usage
echo usage: gitlist ^<path^>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the answer using the locate command: 
[Is there any way to list up git repositories in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101485/is-there-any-way-to-list-up-git-repositories-in-terminal)

The advantages of using locate instead of a custom script are:

1. The search is indexed, so it scales
2. It does not require the use (and maintenance) of a custom bash script

The disadvantages of using locate are:

1. The db that locate uses is updated weekly, so freshly-created git repositories won't show up

Going the locate route, here's how to list all git repositories under a directory, for OS X:

Enable locate indexing (will be different on Linux):

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
```

Run this command after indexing completes (might need some tweaking for Linux):

```
repoBasePath=$HOME
locate '.git' | egrep '.git$' | egrep "^$repoBasePath" | xargs -I {} dirname "{}"
```

Comment: My solution is really fast, and flexible, and adapts to new repos, and does not require a daemon to index the drive periodically. I'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias gtree="fd '\.git$' --prune -utd |  tree --fromfile ."
```

and then you can use `gtree` to find all repos under current directory.

add a bash script mentioned later, you can even cd into any folders of a git repo with tab completion.

## oneliner

I am a big fan of [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) as it is so much faster than find.

```
fd '\.git$' --prune -u -t d -x echo {//}

./group1/repo1
./group1/repo2
./group1/repo3
./group2/repo4
./group2/repo5
```

and with `tree`, it's even better

```
fd '\.git$' --prune -utd |  tree --fromfile .

.
├── group1
│   ├── repo1
│   ├── repo2
│   └── repo3
└── group2
    ├── repo4
    └── repo5
```

## alias

now just add an alias to your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias gtree="fd '\.git$' --prune -utd |  tree --fromfile ."
```

just do `gtree` to find your repo

## bash function w/ completion

If you are crazy like me

```
function gcd {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        FOLDER=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
    else
        FOLDER="$1"
    fi
    cd "$FOLDER"
}

function _list_repos {
    fd '\.git$' --prune -utd -x echo {//} | cut -d/ -f2-
}

function _gcd_complete {
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(_list_repos)" -- "${cur}") )
}

complete -F _gcd_complete gcd
```

now `gcd` tab will get you all the repos under the current directory, or `gcd` when you are deep under a git repo brings you to the root of your git repo.

to pull from all the repos:

```bash
for d in `fd '\.git$' --prune -utd`; do
  pushd $d/..
  echo -e "\n${HIGHLIGHT}Updating `pwd`$NORMAL"
  git pull
  popd
done
```

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. Apologies. In the sample code I show, however, there is `git pull`. This is the purpose: update a tree of git repos. No need to list them. The comments on the question clarify the purpose.

Comment: @MikeSlinn gotcha, thanks for the clarification. but if you pipe the command to a for loop, you can definitely do the same thing. The point is `fd` is so much faster than `find`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\.git$`?

Comment: Thanks, my bad. I've updated it to `\.git$`