# How to recursively find a git repositories with local changes?

Tags: git, recursion

I want to recursively look through directories finding any git repositories with local modifications not synced with the remote. Meaning if I type `git status` there are no files untracked, deleted, renamed, or modified.

**How can this be done?**

Back story: I have a project with several libraries in their own respective repositories. Sometimes I edit these libraries and want to push the changes to their original repo, but I lose track of which libraries I modified and want to find them at the end of a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a script similar to "[How to quickly find all git repos under a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12010862/6309)" in order to find those git repo.
(a pure shell search like `find . -name .git -type d -prune` solution can be more costly than the script referenced here)

That script, for each repo found, will then do a git status, and if needed a git add/commit and push.