# How to detect nested local git repo

Tags: git

I expect I unintentionally created a nested get repo (locally), either by creating a git repo on a higher level or on a lower level.

Is there a quick way to check out if this is the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After asking this question I realized I can just search directories for existing git repo's, and I found a way to do this, from another StackOverflow thread:

running this command in a directory (on Linux) seems to list all git repo's somewhere down the directory tree:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "{}"; git rev-parse --git-dir 2> /dev/null 1>&2' \; -prune -print
```

[Credits go to CharlieB, answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46426222/8110396)

**Note**
Initially I wondered if the command had worked, since the only output I got was a dot (`.`). But of course this meant that the directory I was running this in was a git repo itself.

Running it a level higher gave me the full directory name instead:

```
$ find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "{}"; git rev-parse --git-dir 2> /dev/null 1>&2' \; -prune -print
./01_introduction
```