# List all branches in all local git clones

Tags: git, shell, git-branch

I ended up creating several git clones of various repositories over time, and in some of the clones, I created more than one branch. I want to now find the clone which has a specific branch.

I looked through StackOverflow questions and came across the following post [Git Status Across Multiple Repositories on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765253/git-status-across-multiple-repositories-on-a-mac). Using this as reference, I decided to write my own shell script to do list all clones and the branches in each clone. However, by `grep`ing in the `.git` directory, I could not find any place where this information is available. The `HEAD` file only has information about the currently checked out branch.

I can certainly write a script to process the output of `git branch` in each clone's working directory. However, before I start on that, I would like to know if there is an easier way of obtaining this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.git/refs/heads** should contain all of your local branches.

I am curious -- why isn't using *git branch* in a shell script sufficient?

Comment: Thanks. A shell script would work more or less like following: `find` all the `.git` directories, then `cd` to their `dirname` portion, and then run `git branch` there. But with your answer, it can be simpler (and likely faster, since it only involves shell commands and no git commands). My analysis could be wrong though.

Comment: This is not so simple. [Refs can be packed.](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-refs.html)