# Showing repo status via directory color

Tags: linux, git, zsh

I would like a zsh plugin to show me which git repositories have changes to be pushed based on the color of the root directory.

Ex://
Code
 \Project1
 \Project2

I would like Project1 and Project2 to be colored based on their git status when you run ls from the Code directory.

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

You can try some zsh git theme like [this one](https://gist.github.com/agnoster/3712874), which changes the directory color to reflect a dirty status:

[image: https://raw.github.com/gist/3712874/5d28e2d9fe2e4d0a4fda0315ad97bdafa399425c/screenshot.png]

---

Another alternative is to keep the status color separate from the directory itself: see this [zsh theme](http://blog.joshdick.net/2012/12/30/my_git_prompt_for_zsh.html) (from [Josh Dick](http://joshdick.net/))to shows a "traffic light" representation of git status:

- Red (●) means there are untracked changes.
- Yellow (●) means there are unstaged changes.
- Green (●) means there are staged changes.

[image: http://blog.joshdick.net/asset/post_assets/2012/12/git_zsh_prompt.png]

Comment: I actually already use something similar, but I was looking to have the indicator without actually being in the repo itself, so I could ls my ~/code directory and have all clean/dirty information for all repos.

Comment: @seagoj I understand. I don't know of a "color-based" solution, only of scripts like http://blog.mikepearce.net/2010/06/16/git-status-on-multiple-repos/ or the ones mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/q/2765253/6309.